# Get URL without filename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to figure out how to parse a URL in Rails, and return everything except the filename, or, everything except that which follows the last backslash.

For example, I'd like:

```
http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/directoryname/1234/thumbnail.jpg
```

to become:

```
http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/directoryname/1234/
```

I've found every way to parse a URI, but this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File name

```
"http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/directoryname/1234/thumbnail.jpg".match(/(.*\/)+(.*$)/)[2]
=> "thumbnail.jpg"
```

URL without the file name

```
"http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/directoryname/1234/thumbnail.jpg".match(/(.*\/)+(.*$)/)[1]
=> "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/directoryname/1234/"
```

[String#match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-match)

Comment: I'm trying to return the url _without_ the filename at the end

Answer (score 12):

Ruby has methods available to get you there easily:

```
File.dirname(URL) # => "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/directoryname/1234"
```

Think about what a URL/URI is: It's a designator for a protocol, a site, and a directory-path to a resource. The directory-path to a resource is the same as a "path/to/file", so [`File.dirname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-dirname) works nicely, without having to reinvent that particular wheel.

The trailing `/` isn't included because it's a delimiter between the path segments. You generally don't need that, because joining a resource to a path will automatically supply it.

Really though, using Ruby's [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) class is the proper way to mangle URIs:

```
require 'uri'

URL = 'http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/directoryname/1234/thumbnail.jpg'
uri = URI.parse(URL)
uri.merge('foo.html').to_s 
# => "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/directoryname/1234/foo.html"
```

[URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) allows you to mess with the path easily too:

```
uri.merge('../foo.html').to_s 
# => "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/directoryname/foo.html"

uri.merge('../bar/foo.html').to_s 
# => "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/directoryname/bar/foo.html"
```

[URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) is well-tested, and designed for this purpose. It will also allow you to add query parameters easily, encoding them as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
'http://a.b.pl/a/b/c/d.jpg'.rpartition('/').first
=> "http://a.b.pl/a/b/c"
```